# How to orginize a DB that is used to compare tables, where the main index is generated AFTER the creation? (JS + Node + MySQL + sequelize)

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js, sequelize.js

I'll try to explain it as simple as I can, imagine the tables looking like that:

Working on Project X

| ID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 157 | Dan |
| 234 | Ben |
| 276 | Jess |

Working on Project Z:

| ID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 157 | Danny |
| 567 | Franklin |

Workers Index:

| ID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 157 | Daniel |
| 234 | Benjamin |
| 276 | Jessica |
| 375 | Arnold |
| 567 | Frank |

And I want to do a query starting from the main index to get something like

| ID | Name | name on project X | name on Project Z |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 157 | Daniel | Dan | Danny |
| 234 | Benjamin | Ben | null |
| 567 | Frank | null | Franklin |

Now I can make it work with LEFT JOIN, but I don't know how can I implement some data integrity here, and make it simple using sequelize.
The main problem is that the main index is created AFTER the projects are created.
It kinda looks like that:

1. creates the projects tables (without worker ID).
2. Generate worker ID
3. Create a MAIN INDEX by going through all the tables.
4. Query based on the ID in the main index to know which worker is working on which project, based on the ID.

Is there a way to create these connections? And how would I query based on this DB?

Edit:
When searching I am using an Array of IDs

Answer (score 0):

First, let's lay out the tables needed:

`workers`: with real name and `worker_id` for the PRIMARY KEY
`projects`: with `project_id`, etc
`w_p`: a many to many mapping table with `worker_id` and `nickname` and `project_id`; `PRIMARY KEY(project_id, worker_id), INDEX(worker_id, project_id)`

Now make a stab at the desired `SELECT`.

Comment: So you're saying that instead of having a separate table for each project, I should have one only giving them different IDs to be used in the one big table with workers and projects? I am afraid it would only make it messier for times when I need to update the project table, delete rows and so on. Or if I want to just read from that 1 table

Comment: It is almost always a "bad" schema design to have lots if 'identical' tables.  So, yes, I am steering you away from that.